# Anybody have any idea how the divs are emitted in pinterest.com?

Tags: layout, html, pinterest

I tried rendering my div images like this horizontally (left-to-right, top-to-bottom).
But it's not quite right.
Wondering if it's just vertically done where each column is rendered (top-to-bottom, right-to-left).

Anybody have any idea how to mimic/replicate this page?

*** Update ***
In response to the answer below, i did a quick search for "masonry vs isotope". The following **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856893/difference-between-isotope-and-masonry-jquery-plugins)** explains this question very well, for all those interested.

Comment: have you tried viewing source / use firebug / chrome console to try to find out how they layout their divs?

Comment: i actually tried to do this, but it wasnt human readable (i was just eye-balling the source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each item is placed dynamically with JavaScript. Try viewing it with JS turned off. They are probably using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), or something similar.