# How to float div's with variable heights at same distance: Solution without Masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float, floating

How to position floating div's with fixed widths but variable heights at the same vertical distance of each other?

Similar questions like this have been asked a lot and almost always is the answer use masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Masonry is a good solution, but masonry does more than needed.

What would be a simple jquery/css solution which doesn't require a library like masonry or packery (http://packery.metafizzy.co/)?

Problem:

[image: 1]

Intended result:

[image: 2]

Images are from this questions: [Floating divs with variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913369/floating-divs-with-variable-height)

Related questions:

[CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights)

[Floating divs with variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913369/floating-divs-with-variable-height)

Example HTML:

```
<style>
    #wrapper {
        width: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

    .block {
        width: 180px;
        float: left;
        background-color: green;
        margin: 5px;

    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block" style="height:100px;">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height:140px;">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height:70px;">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height:120px;">
    </div>
    <div class="block" style="height:170px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think unless you're willing to restrict the boundaries of your question quite a bit, your answer is going to be the same as the already asked questions which are basically duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers that support CSS columns, you can use [this](http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/) technique posted by Radu Chelariu on Sick Designer.

You can configure the #wrapper element to have 3 columns like this:

```
#wrapper {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}

#wrapper div.block {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Display inline-block, and absolutely NO FLOATS! */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That would work if to forget about order of elements.

Comment: @c-smile Good point. The ordering of the child elements would be different from a masonry implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Without js, there is one CSS3 way you can implement it using **CSS3 Columns** like `column-count`, `column-gap`.

Check out the link, http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: Thanks, but JS or jquery is not a problem, I was looking for something smaller than the 25kb of masonry. Great simple solution, although browser support and the order of the content might give some trouble.

Comment: for jquery plugin, try this which is smaller file size http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/

Comment: That's really a small plugin. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'inline-block' and 'vertical-align' for div's

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4vm5cpu/

Your block will behave like inline elements

Comment: The space problem is the same as with the floating blocks.

Comment: Yes, but block are arranged in strict lines. If you wont fixed vertical space between blocks, I think the best way is to go with column solution

Answer (score 0):

In [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/main.whtm) this can be done as

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>

    #wrapper {
        width: 400px;
        flow: "1 2 3"   
              "1 4 3";
    }

    .block {
        width: 180px;
        background-color: gold;
        margin: 5px;
    }    

    </style>

  </head>
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <span class="block" style="height:160px;">1</span>
    <span class="block" style="height:100px;">2</span>
    <span class="block" style="height:240px;">3</span>
    <span class="block" style="height:200px;">4</span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

as it supports `flow:"template"` among other layout managers.

That above is rendered as [image]

In conventional browsers, without support of module grid that's not viable without JS.