# Vaadin 7 Isotope or Quicksand components for elements sorting animation

Tags: vaadin, jquery-isotope, vaadin7

I'm just wondering if there is an implementation/adapter of JavaScript component Isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html for Vaadin 7 framework ?

I need [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html) or [Quicksand](https://razorjack.net/quicksand/) or some similar component with a sorting animation effect. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you need? If u need sorting, use Collections.sort() on your components in the layout. If u need animations during sorting then the answer is no. You need to implement it yourself

Comment: @kukis  I need Isotope or some similar component for Vaadin for animation effect during sorting

Answer (score 1):

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is very similar to [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) - a comparison is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856893/difference-between-isotope-and-masonry-jquery-plugins).

Given this, there exists 2 Vaadin 'Masonry-style' components.

- https://github.com/alump/Masonry
- https://github.com/lotsabackscatter/vaadin-masonry-cards

The alump component is more actively maintained and seems to have most of the interesting features of the Masonry library implemented.
You can try it here: http://app.siika.fi/MasonryDemo/ and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: I have reviewed Masonry and looks like it lacks dynamic sorting of attached elements.  I need Isotope or some similar component for Vaadin for animation effect during sorting.

Comment: Yeah I'm not aware of any other libaries. Alump's Masonry component does have a drag and drop facility (http://app.siika.fi/MasonryDemo/#!VaadinDnDTestsView) but the animation on it looks a bit dodgy.. I haven't played with it myself too much though.